# pdflatex starting as pdftex, doesn't respond to -fmt option

Tags: pdftex, miktex

Just installed MiKTeX 21.8 on Windows 7 and it will not behave.  Running pdflatex from TeXMaker gets me:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdftex 2021.10.8) 8 OCT 2021 14:27
```

Setting `-fmt pdflatex` makes no difference.

Needless to say I am unable to compile any documents as it pretends to wholly not understand the LaTeX source:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\documentclass
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you get if you start pdflatex in an terminal/console?

Comment: On windows 10 I have no problems. miktex doesn't officially support windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps some wrong with your code?  I am running windows 7 x64, Texstudio and `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.13)  8 OCT 2021 `  Using `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode   -shell-escape %.tex`

Comment: Running plain pdflatex with no arguments gets:
    C:\>pdflatex
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10)
    **
(with a command prompt for interaction)

Comment: Are you really trying to run `pdftex -fmt pdflatex ... `? Why not jsut run `pdflatex`?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I do. It always thinks it's pdftex. Here's my Tekmaker config: https://i.imgur.com/rn1Yryc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On closer inspection, `-fmt` isn't even an option. I saw it in some related responses but it seems they were irrelevant.

On a whim, I opened TeXworks; surely the tool that comes in the box can do it somehow?  Lo and behold it does.  Turns out it uses the `-undump=pdflatex` option, which is what's required.  This turns pdftex into pdflatex.  I have no idea why the .exe doesn't do *what it says in the filename*, but I can build documents now.